# Creating TCP listening socket in Chrome App: "Does not have permission"

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am writing a Google Chrome Application, and I want it to open a TCP listening socket.

Here are the relevant parts of the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
   "app": { ... }
   "manifest_version" : 2,
   "permissions" : { ... }, // None of the permissions seem relevant here?!?
   "sockets" : {
      "tcp": { "connect" : ["*"] },
      "tcpServer" : { "listen" : ["127.0.0.1:1763"] }
   }
}
```

The code where I attempt to open the socket:

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create(
      { 
         persistent: true, 
          name: "My socket" 
      }, 
     (socketCreateInfo) => {
           console.log(`chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create callback invoked. 
           socketId=${socketCreateInfo.socketId}`);
           const socketId = socketCreateInfo.socketId;
           chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(
               socketId, 
               "127.0.0.1", 
                1763, 
                resultCode => {
                     if (typeof (resultCode) === "undefined") {
                          console.log(`listen callback error! "${chrome.runtime.lastError.message}"`);
                    }
                    else {
                      console.log(`listen callback with resultCode ${resultCode}`);
                      this.onListenCallback(socketId, resultCode);
                    }
             });
     });
```

And the output console logs:

> chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create callback invoked. socketId=22
>
> listen callback error! "Does not have permission"

But I requested the permission in the manifest! Why would this be failing?

Answer (score 0):

The code in my question is actually fine.

Here's my mistake: I was testing this as a local, unpacked extension on Windows. If you change the manifest.json file, you must uninstall and reinstall the extension for these changes to take effect.

Once I uninstalled and reinstalled my chrome app, this worked.

Comment: An explicit _reload_ through `chrome://extensions/` should be sufficient for the changes you mention - did you try that? There _are_ some rare cases when a reinstall is needed, _removing_ permissions being one of them.